# How to commit stored procedure execution by using pyodbc

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to execute stored procedure by using pyodbc in databricks, after executing SP I tried to commit the connection but, commit is not happening.  Here I am giving my code, please help me out from this issue.

```
import pyodbc

####   Connecting Azure SQL
def db_connection():
  try:
    username = "starsusername"
    password = "password-db"
    server = "server-name"
    database_name = "db-name2"
    port = "db-port"
    conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server};SERVER=tcp:'+server+','+port+';DATABASE='+ database_name +';UID='+ username +';PWD='+ password)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    return cursor, conn
  except Exception as e:
    print("Faild to Connect AZURE SQL: \n"+str(e))

cursor, conn = db_connection()
# conn1.autocommit=True
cursor.execute("delete from db.table_name")
cursor.execute("insert into db.table_name(BUSINESS_DATE) values('2021-10-02')")
cursor.execute("exec db.SP_NAME '20211023'")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

here I am commiting connection after SP excution. deletion and insertion is not happening at all. and I tried with cursor.execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; exec db.SP_NAME '20211023'") but it's also not working.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you check this **[document on pyodbc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/StoredProcedures.wiki)**, you will find that -

> To call a stored procedure right now, pass the call to the execute method using either a format your database recognizes or using the ODBC call escape format. The ODBC driver will then reformat the call for you to match the given database.

Note that after connection is set up or done, try doing `conn.autocommit = True` before calling your SP and it will help. By default it is false.

1. ##### Executing the Stored Procedure.

   You will be able to execute your stored procedure if you follow the below code snippet.

   ```py
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   conn.autocommit = True
   executesp = """EXEC yourstoredprocedure """
   cursor.execute(executesp)
   conn.commit()
   ```
2. ##### Delete the Records in SQL Server

   You can delete record as shown in the below example.

   ```py
   ...#just an example
   cursor.execute('''
               DELETE FROM product 
               WHERE product_id in (5,6) 
              ''')
   conn.commit()
   ```

   Don’t forget to add **conn.commit()** at the end of the code, to ensure that the command would get executed.
3. ##### Insert record in SQL Server

   The below snippet show how we can do the same.

   ```py
   ...#just an example
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO EMP (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR) VALUES (535, 'Scott', 'Manager', 545)")
   conn.commit()
   ```

I will suggest you to read the for following document for more information.

- [Delete Record Documentation](https://cppsecrets.com/users/1173109101103104971091051161169710849545464103109971051084699111109/Python-SQL-Server-delete-record.php).
- [Insert Record Document](https://www.devart.com/odbc/sqlazure/docs/python.htm)

Comment: instead of commit three times I just want to commit once (at last) and when i tried to execute  SP itself, SP execution is done and connection closed in python but it's still running in SSMS backend. nothing is changed in target tables (insertion, deletion..)

Comment: Yes, you can do that also instead of doing commit at each step you can commit only once at the end.